# Background extraction in Python using open CV

Tags: python, opencv, background

I am trying to extract a background image from a video so I can detect moving objects in it.
I have found functions like  cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(), however I just can't get it to work.
Does someone have some experience using this ?

I have created object `mog = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG(300,-1,-1,-1)`

Then I try `mog.apply(Nmat,Nforemat,-1)`, but that doesnt seem to work, I get the following
error:

> ......\OpenCV-2.4.0\modules\video\src\bgfg_gaussmix.cpp:117: error: (-215) CV_MAT_DEPTH(frameType) == CV_8U

Nmat and N foremat are numpy arrays because i was also getting an error if they weren't.

Here is work in progress...

```
import cv
import cv2
import numpy as np

if __name__ == '__main__':
  cv.NamedWindow("test1", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
  cv.NamedWindow("test2", cv.CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
  capture = cv.CreateFileCapture('test.avi')
  frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)

  img = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,1)
  thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,1)
  foreground = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(frame),8,1)
  foremat = cv.GetMat(foreground)
  Nforemat = np.array(foremat, dtype=np.float32)

  thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8,1)
  mog = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()

  loop = True
  nframes=0
  while(loop):
    frame = cv.QueryFrame(capture)
    mat = cv.GetMat(frame)
    Nmat = np.array(mat, dtype=np.float32)

    cv.CvtColor(frame,img,cv.CV_BGR2GRAY)

    if (frame == None):
        break

    mog.apply(Nmat,Nforemat,-1)
    cv.Threshold(img,thresh,100,255,cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)

    cv.ShowImage("test1", thresh)
    cv.ShowImage("test2",frame)
    char = cv.WaitKey(50)
    if (char != -1):
        if (char == 27):
                break
  cv.DestroyWindow("test1")
  cv.DestroyWindow("test2")
```

Comment: if use use the cv2 versions of the opencv functions they are numby arrays already

Comment: Thx, that was useful, I have rewritten the code using only cv2 functions from library and all works! 
Of course little modifications in code were made since i missed usings of some methods.

Comment: It would be nice to see your answer with the cv2 code. Can you share it?

Answer (score 1):

change

```
Nmat = np.array(mat, dtype=np.float32)
```

for

```
Nmat = np.array(mat, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Comment: However, it doesn't seem to subtract the background

Comment: That could work, however I ended up using only cv2 library and that resolved the problem .

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using these lines:

```
thresh = cv.CreateImage(cv.GetSize(img),8,1)
```

and

```
cv.Threshold(img,thresh,100,255,cv.CV_THRESH_BINARY)
```

?

Comment: Hi there! Welcome to SO, and thanks for contributing. Questions to the original poster should typically be added as comments on the question themselves, and not as answers.

Comment: thresh was thrown out, didn't need it anymore, and i used cv2.threshold in final version for getting image in binary format.